# How to add user input into a dictionary with enumerated keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, input, enumeration

I've been working on a lab about manipulating dictionaries and how to read them. I got stuck on a problem that makes us ask for a user input that will add it to the dictionary.

The reason why I'm stuck is because I have enumerated the input for keys and I don't know how to add more to the dictionary without worrying about the keys. Would I have to take a few step backs and rework on how the keys are created?

```
dInput = input('Please enter a string ')
D = dict(enumerate(dInput))
print(D)
## This is where I enumerate the user input

plusDict = input('Enter another character to add to the dictionary ')
## User puts in a character and the script adds it to the dictionary with it's proper key.
```

In an example:

```
Please enter a string: fff
{0: 'f', 1: 'f', 2: 'f'}

Enter another character to add to the dictionary: e
```

*desired result*:

```
{0: 'f', 1: 'f', 2: 'f', 3: 'e'}
```

I've erased most of the script that allows the user to access the dictionary through input, as this is the only spot I'm stuck in. Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Do you want to [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) a dictionary?

Comment: If this is the exact behavior you want, you can do `d[len(d)] = plusDict`, though I'm left wondering what makes it different from a list at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to rewrite the code. If all you want to do is add a new character with its key being the next available integer, just do:

```
D[len(D)] = plusDict
```

If you want to add multiple characters at once, you can do:

```
for char in plusDict: D[len(D)] = char
```

Comment: what if `plusDict` is more than one character?

Comment: @Tomerikoo The OP literally says "another character". If it is more than one, then the user didn't follow directions. But, sure, I see your point. Updated my answer.

Comment: Man, I knew it was something as simple as that. I wrote D[x] = plusDict in the script knowing it was similar to that. Appreciate it!

Comment: @FernandoFlores no problem. feel free to mark the correct answer if your problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate takes an optional second argument that tells it where to start. You can keep track of this and use it when enumerating to make the values continually increase. (Of course you know a list would be better for this).

```
D = {}
index = 0

dInput = input('Please enter a string ')
# input abc
D.update(enumerate(dInput, index))
index += len(dInput)
print(D)
# prints 
# {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}


dInput = input('Please enter a string ')
# input def
D.update(enumerate(dInput, index))
index += len(dInput)
print(D)
# {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f'}
```